# Git apache : unable to push via http

Tags: apache-2.2, git

I have to setup a server which can allow http vcs management (such as git and svn).
svn support works well, but I have some trouble with git.
Actual configuration:

- CentOS 5
- Apache 2.2.8
- Git 1.7.4.1

The /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf content:

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 120
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 10
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
Listen 80
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule mysql_auth_module modules/mod_auth_mysql.so
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
Include conf.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin aedi.admin@domain
ServerName s1.domain
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/data/www/"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/data/www/">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disable
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
ServerSignature On
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</IfModule>
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html
AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /data/www/s1/html
    ServerName s1.asso.domain
    ErrorLog logs/s1.error.log
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /data/www/s2/old
    ServerName s2.domain
    ErrorLog logs/s2.error.log
    RailsBaseURI /blog
    <Directory /data/www/s2/html/blog>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /data/www/s2/html
    ServerName s2.domain
    ErrorLog logs/s2.error.log
    RailsBaseURI /blog
    <Directory /data/www/s2/html/blog>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The /etc/httpd/conf.d/git.conf content:

```
Alias /git /data/www/s2/git

<Directory /data/www/s2/git>
        Options +Indexes

        DAV on
        SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

Fine, every repository are created by the same way:

```
   git --bare init "$1.git"
&& cd "$1.git"
&& git update-server-info && chmod -R 770 .
&& cd ..
&& git clone `pwd`/"$1.git"
&& cd "$1"
&& echo 42 > answer && git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit"
&& git push origin master
&& git rm answer && git commit -a -m "Clean repository"
&& git push
&& cd .. && rm -Rf "$1"
```

Then, on the client side, I try:

> ```
> ~ $ git clone https://s2.domain/git/repo.git
> Cloning into 'repo'...
> warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
> ~ $ cd repo
> repo $ echo 42 > answer && git add . && git commit -m "init" && git push origin master
> [master (root-commit) a2aadb1] init
>  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
>  create mode 100644 answer
> Fetching remote heads...
>   refs/
>   refs/heads/
>   refs/tags/
> updating 'refs/heads/master'
>   from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   to   a2aadb1772e12104ce358f7ff9a11db5d93ead7d
>     sending 3 objects
> MOVE d81cc0710eb6cf9efd5b920a8453e1e07157b6cd failed, aborting (22/502)
> MOVE 2c186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b failed, aborting (22/502)
> MOVE a2aadb1772e12104ce358f7ff9a11db5d93ead7d failed, aborting (22/502)
> Updating remote server info
> fatal: git-http-push failed
> ```

The apache associated logs:

> ```
> my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:19 +0200] "GET /git/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-"
> ```
>
> "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:19 +0200] "GET /git/repo.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:48 +0200] "GET /git/repo.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-"
>   "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "GET /git/repo.git/HEAD HTTP/1.1" 200 23 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/ HTTP/1.1" 207 569 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "HEAD /git/repo.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "HEAD /git/repo.git/objects/info/packs HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MKCOL /git/repo.git/info/ HTTP/1.1" 405 336 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "LOCK /git/repo.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 200 475 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "GET /git/repo.git/objects/info/packs HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2608 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 207 941 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/tags/ HTTP/1.1" 207 940 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MKCOL /git/repo.git/refs/ HTTP/1.1" 405 336 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MKCOL /git/repo.git/refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 405 342 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "LOCK /git/repo.git/refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 200 475 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/objects/a2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 317 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/objects/2c/ HTTP/1.1" 207 4565 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/objects/d8/ HTTP/1.1" 207 4565 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PUT /git/repo.git/objects/d8/1cc0710eb6cf9efd5b920a8453e1e07157b6cd_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 201 373 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MKCOL /git/repo.git/objects/a2/ HTTP/1.1" 201 296 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PUT /git/repo.git/objects/2c/186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 201 373 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MOVE /git/repo.git/objects/d8/1cc0710eb6cf9efd5b920a8453e1e07157b6cd_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 502 341 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MOVE /git/repo.git/objects/2c/186ad49fa24695512df5e41cb5e6f2d33c119b_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 502 341 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PUT /git/repo.git/objects/a2/aadb1772e12104ce358f7ff9a11db5d93ead7d_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 201 373 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "MOVE /git/repo.git/objects/a2/aadb1772e12104ce358f7ff9a11db5d93ead7d_20ca3a58daa09e54112968cbd4e86580b6301074
>   HTTP/1.1" 502 341 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "UNLOCK /git/repo.git/refs/heads/master HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2608 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/heads/ HTTP/1.1" 207 941 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "PROPFIND /git/repo.git/refs/tags/ HTTP/1.1" 207 940 "-" "git/1.7.11.4"
>       my.ip - - [21/Sep/2012:16:19:49 +0200] "UNLOCK /git/repo.git/info/refs HTTP/1.1" 204 - "-" "git/1.7.11.4"

I have tried many configurations (even smart http from progit), but a major part of them consider the fact that they have a dedicated domain, but I'm in a sub-directory, so I can't apply these examples.
Have you got an idea of the problem? have you got solutions? have you got configuration example with non-root directory?

For your help,
In advance,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I switch to Grack (https://github.com/schacon/grack) and it works out of the box!